# SQL server Query Q - tuples

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-masking

SQL statement that would give an alias to a tuple that meets a specific condition ?

**Not to Change the content of the database.** Just the query that when (in this example) the city field is Portland to set it's alias as A instead. But the underlying database for this table and this field, it will still be Portland.

[image]

Comment: you are talking about masking the data. alias is more of the column or table

Comment: which version of sql-server?

Comment: I use both SQL server 2014 and SQL server 2008.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: for 2014 you can also use IIF

Answer (score 0):

I use [case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) in that cases
IE

```
select 
id, 
name, 
case city 
    when 'Portland' then 
        'anotherthing'
    else city 
 end as mycolumn   -- can be the same column CITY
 from mydata;
```

another way to do that is using like says another person iif

```
select 
id, 
name, 
iif(city = 'Portland',
    'anotherthing',
     city 
) as mycolumn   -- can be the same column CITY
 from mydata;
```

I hope be helpful

Comment: would help if you name the calculated column

Comment: I just add an alias

Comment: Thank you, looks good. But in my 2014, I use similar code to what you have and not IIF and it works fine.

Comment: both works fine but IIF is easier to look at and less code.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done with a linked lookup table.  For example if you had a table with the columns "original_name" and "new_name" then your sql would look like this:

```
Select a.address, a.addressline1, b.new_name
from atable a
join lookuptable b on a.original_name = b.original_name
```

You put all your lookup values in the lookup table and you can change them (or add to them) when needed.  Unlike a case clause you don't have to change your sql.

Comment: you are actually defining an alias table or a dictionary but this will require additional work. it really depends on the requirement. i do understand your point.

Comment: I think this will require less work in the long run because it will be easier to maintain, faster, and clearer design.  But if it is really to hard to make a table you can put a look-up in a view, CTE or values sub-query, all of which is better than a case statement.

Comment: agreed. now it's up to him

Comment: Where do you get lookuptable and new_name ?  I tried to do what you just did but I don't know where you get those two and original_name.

Comment: So you are creating a temp table from the original table and change the column City where is Portland to A and you just do a look up (join) between the temp table and the original and pull the manipulated field (new_name) ?  sorry just trying to understand.

Comment: Hogan, thanks for showing the new approach. I think is very good. The only concern I have with temp table is that sometimes when someone manipulate tables and data in a database via temp tables etc, they end up accidentally make changes not to the temp table but instead the real table - like added, changing or deleting. I wonder how do you advise to prevent this ?  And I guess I am not sure if when the database table update would the temp table reflect the updates. Other than that I think your idea is great. And maybe there are many many great aspect with your way if I see or try it.

Comment: @Johnseito -- it does not have to be a temp table -- in the production system I work with we have many tables like this that are not temp tables..  Also I do not understand how changing a "temp table" would change the real table.  I think you might have to show me some code.  Do you mean a view?

Comment: @Johnseito ... familiar with synonyms in the dictionary? that's the idea